# Thymeleaf throws an error when outputting the object id to the template

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a object `format`, when I try to output to the id value, thymeleaf throws an error.
Spring Security dependency is also enabled.

Template code

```
<label th:each = "format : ${Format}" th:attr="for='label' + ${format.title}" class="btn_order">
    <sup th:text = "${format.title}"/>
    <sup th:text = "${format.price}"/>
    <input class = "radio_settings" name = "price_reload" th:value="${format.id}"   th:attr="id='label' + ${format.title}" type="radio" hidden>
</label>
```

Entity Format

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Format")
public class Format {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer lenght;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer width;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer height;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer weight;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float price;
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping()
    public String getWindowOrder(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("title","Create order");
        model.addAttribute("Format", formatService.getByAll());
        return "window_order";
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class FormatService {

@Autowired
private FormatInterface iFormat;

public List<Format> getByAll (){
        return iFormat.findByAll();
    }
}
```

WebConfigSecurity

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/registration/**",  "/create/**", "/cart" ,"/image/**", "/css/**", "/js/**","/order","/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

Error

```
ERROR 10344 --- [io-8080-exec-10] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-10] Exception processing template "window_cart": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/window_order.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/window_order.html]")
```

All other class data is displayed correctly. If you remove `th:value = "${format.id}"` , then the template is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the point is that you need to address the id with capital characters

```html
<div class="settings_format">
  <label th:each = "format : ${Format}"           th:attr="for=${format.ID}" class="btn_order">
    <sup th:text = "${format.title}"/>
    <input class = "radio_settings" name = "format_id" th:attr="value=${format.ID},id=${format.ID}" type="radio" hidden>
  </label>
</div>
```